# Asignar el contenido de una lista en python a una variable de objeto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

Como puedo asignar el contenido de una lista utilizando la funcion jsonify de python flask a una variable dentro de un script en javascript.

```
@app.route('/menu')
def menu():
    """Renders la pagina menu."""
    conexion = Conexion()
    registros = conexion.consulta_sql("SELECT * FROM tabla")
    return render_template('menu.html', title = 'Menu AppseresWeb', menu_registros = jsonify(registros))
```

y quiero almacenarla aquí (esto es dentro del template menu.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var datos = JSON.parse('{{ menu_registros }}'); </script>
```

Comment: Creo que las comillas en la parte javascript deben ser dobles `"{{ menu_registros }}"`. Pero eso puede causarte problemas si el JSON en cuestión tiene comillas a su vez, pues habría que escaparlas. Y pensándolo mejor ¿a qué la desjsonificación? Yo creo que esto debería funcionar sin más: `var datos = {{ menu_registros }};`, pues a fin de cuentas el JSON es javascript válido.

Comment: No creo que sea la manera correcta. En tu lugar intentaría obtener ese dato mediante una llamada AJAX. Las variables que manejas en Flask para las plantillas son para hacer un *render* con esos datos, no para pasarlas a la lógica del lado cliente. Saludos

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, me parece que con la llamada de AJAX se puede resolver. Muchas gracias por la colaboración, saludos